# Need to remove the count from the output when using "uniq -c" command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to read a file and sort it by number of occurrences of a particular field. Suppose I want to find out the most repeated date from a log file; then I use uniq -c option and sort it in descending order, something like this

```
uniq -c | sort -nr
```

This will produce some output like this -

```
809 23/Dec/2008:19:20
```

The first field, which is actually the count, is the problem for me. I want to get only the date from the above output but I’m not able to get this. I tried to use cut command and did this

```
uniq -c | sort -nr | cut -d' ' -f2
```

but this just prints blank space. Please can someone help me on getting the date only and chop off the count. I want only

```
23/Dec/2008:19:20
```

Comment: are you sure your output looks like that? I tried `echo '809 23/Dec/2008:19:20' | cut -d' ' -f2` and it works fine

Comment: Depending on the implementation of `uniq` in use, there might be zero or more spaces before the repeat count `809`.  Without leading blanks, the original expression would work fine.  Because some implementations of `uniq -c` do produce leading blanks, it runs into problems.

Comment: Jonathan .. that was a perfect guess .... i see that there is a blank space before the count.

Comment: regardless the input: sort fist then uniq

Comment: can you show the input data?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov I added examples..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The count from `uniq` is preceded by spaces unless there are more than 7 digits in the count, so you need to do something like:

```
uniq -c | sort -nr | cut -c 9-
```

to get columns (character positions) 9 upwards.  Or you can use `sed`:

```
uniq -c | sort -nr | sed 's/^.\{8\}//'
```

or:

```
uniq -c | sort -nr | sed 's/^ *[0-9]* //'
```

This second option is robust in the face of a repeat count of 10,000,000 or more; if you think that might be a problem, it is probably better than the `cut` alternative.  And there are undoubtedly other options available too.

---

Caveat: the counts were determined by experimentation on Mac OS X 10.7.3 but using GNU `uniq` from `coreutils` 8.3.  The BSD `uniq -c` produced 3 leading spaces before a single digit count.  The POSIX spec says the output from [`uniq -c`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html) shall be formatted as if with:

```
printf("%d %s", repeat_count, line);
```

which would not have any leading blanks.  Given this possible variance in output formats, the `sed` script with the `[0-9]` regex is the most reliable way of dealing with the variability in observed and theoretical output from `uniq -c`:

```
uniq -c | sort -nr | sed 's/^ *[0-9]* //'
```

Comment: Thanks .... it helped a lot and I learnt a new command sed. I am still new to this shell scripting.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `cut -d' ' -f2`, try

```
awk '{$1="";print}'
```

Maybe you need to remove one more blank in the beginning:

```
awk '{$1="";print}' | sed 's/^.//'
```

or completly with sed, preserving original whitspace:

```
sed -r 's/^[^0-9]*[0-9]+//'
```

Comment: Nice: generic solution, independent of OS & `uniq` version.

Answer (score 3):

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk '{a[$0]++} END{for(i in a){print a[i],i | "sort -k2"}}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In case you want order of output to be same as input but not as sort.

```
awk '!a[$0]++{b[++count]=$0} {c[$0]++} END{for(i=1;i<=count;i++){print c[b[i]],b[i]}}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

an alternative solution is this:

```
uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{print $1, $2}'
```

also you may easily print a single field.

Comment: This only works if the second field doesn't contain any whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

use(since you use -f2 in the cut in your question)

```
cat file |sort |uniq -c | awk '{ print $2; }'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with the count field downstream, following command will reformat it to a 'pipe friendly' tab delimited format without the left padding:

```
 .. | sort | uniq -c | sed -r 's/^ +([0-9]+) /\1\t/'
```

For the original task it is a bit of an overkill, but after reformatting, `cut` can be used to remove the field, as OP intended:

```
 .. | sort | uniq -c | sed -r 's/^ +([0-9]+) /\1\t/' | cut -d $'\t' -f2-
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `tr -s` to the pipe chain to "squeeze" multiple spaces into one space delimiter:

```
uniq -c | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f3
```

`tr` is very useful in some obscure places. Unfortunately it doesn't get rid of the first leading space, hence the `-f3`

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `sed` to strip both the leading spaces and the numbers printed by `uniq -c`

```
sort file | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *[0-9]* //'
```

I would illustrate this with an example. Consider a file

```
winebottles.mkv
winebottles.mov
winebottles.xges
winebottles.xges~
winebottles.mkv
winebottles.mov
winebottles.xges
winebottles.xges~
```

The command

```
sort file | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *[0-9]* //'
```

would return

```
winebottles.mkv
winebottles.mov
winebottles.xges
winebottles.xges~
```

Comment: Actually this solution will be useful only for file composed just by letters. So it'll fit with the sample provided, but not for real-case scenarios.

Comment: @Shred I have added an example that would illustrate the way sed strips the prefix.

Comment: Lose the [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) though.

Answer (score 0):

**first solution**
just using `sort` when input repetition has not been taken into consideration. `sort` has unique option `-u`

- `sort -u file`
- `sort -u < file`

Ex.:

```
$ cat > file
a
b
c
a
a
g
d
d
$ sort -u file
a
b
c
d
g
```

**second solution**
if `sort`ing based on repetition is important

- `sort txt | uniq -c | sort -k1 -nr | sed 's/^ \+[0-9]\+ //g'`
- `sort txt | uniq -c | sort -k1 -nr | perl -lpe  's/^ +[\d]+ +//g'`

which has this output:

```
a
d
g
c
b
```

Comment: yes *sort* has that option, but you can't make *uniq* produce additional info then (in this case the count), since you have unique records only at that point